# Item Template for Web and/or MVC in a VSIX?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-templates

Is there a way to specify what type of project an item template is for besides CSharp and VB? I have tried setting ProjectType to Web and ProjectSubType to CSharp as it says in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171386(v=vs.110).aspx. This causes the item template to not appear anywhere. I've also tried the reverse, which gets it to show up under C#, but not under web.

Ideally I'd like for it to show under MVC, but even Web would just be fine. How can do I that?
Since this is a VSIX I can't and don't want to just drop it into the appropriate area of the item templates folder.

```
<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
  <ProjectSubType>Web</ProjectSubType>
<RequiredFrameworkVersion>4.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
<NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>2</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your project file to pastebin or somewhere? There's a few ways to do this but it's somewhat dependent upon how you have your projects currently set up.

Comment: What profile file are you referring to? I have one solution with 3 projects (item template, vsix project, template wizard), do you want the .csproj file of one of them? Or the .vstemplate or .vsmanifest file or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mimic the hierarchy in you VSIX project where you included the template file. For example, if you want the template to appear under the node `Web` under `C#` and you have the template file under the folder `ItemTemplates` in your VSIX project, you need to move the template file to:

`ItemTemplates > CSharp > Web`

Then: 
`<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>`
`<NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>`

Would be sufficient. You don't need to set `<ProjectSubType></ProjectSubType>`